# ListView CheckBox data binding - remove checked items

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, checkbox, data-binding

I am trying to remove all checked items in my listview when I click on the delete button.
[image: ListView]

I have seen `IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected"` being mentioned quite some places, but I do not know how I should combine it with my already IsChecked binding.

In my code, this is throwing an exception:
`lvStores.Items.Remove(item);`

I am importing CSV files with the following structure:
*"ID","NAME",CheckedINT*
e.g.
**"1662","BØRSTER",0** <-- where 1 = checked, 0 = unchecked.
**"1658","BØRSTER",1**

I am using this to loop through the data in the ListView in another method:

```
    // Loop through ListView
    foreach (var item in lvStores.Items.OfType<Store>())
    {
        // If 1 item in Listview is checked then
        if (item.IsChecked == true)
        {
            blnOk = true;
            return;
        }
    }
```

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="CloneMacro.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CloneMacro"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Clone Macro" Height="348" Width="620.045" Closed="MainWindow_Closed" Icon="C:\Users\Niclas VMWare\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\CloneMacro\CloneMacro\images\copy.png">
    <Grid Background="#FFDEDEDE" Margin="-1,0,-8,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="621">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="cmdNew" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="39,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="39" Height="40" ToolTip="New" Click="cmdNew_Click">
            <Image x:Name="imgNew" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="37" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="36" Source="C:\Users\Niclas VMWare\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\CloneMacro\CloneMacro\images\Generic_Document.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.172,1.089"/>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="cmdOpen" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="39" Height="40" ToolTip="Open" Click="cmdOpen_Click">
            <Image x:Name="imgOpen" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="37" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="36" Source="C:\Users\Niclas VMWare\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\CloneMacro\CloneMacro\images\folder_Open_32xLG.png"/>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="cmdSave" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="121,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="39" Height="40" ToolTip="Save" Click="cmdSave_Click">
            <Image x:Name="imgSave" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="37" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="36" Source="C:\Users\Niclas VMWare\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\CloneMacro\CloneMacro\images\save_16xLG.png"/>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="cmdDelete" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="235,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="39" Height="40" Click="cmdDelete_Click">
            <Image x:Name="imgDelete" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="33" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="32" Source="C:\Users\Niclas VMWare\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\CloneMacro\CloneMacro\images\action_Cancel_16xLG.png" ToolTip="Delete" RenderTransformOrigin="1.334,0.534"/>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="cmdNewStore" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="275,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="39" Height="40" Click="cmdNewStore_Click">
            <Image x:Name="imgNewStore" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="37" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="36" Source="C:\Users\Niclas VMWare\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\CloneMacro\CloneMacro\images\action_add_16xLG.png" ToolTip="Add New Store" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="cmdExecute" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="355,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="39" Height="40" ToolTip="Execute" Click="cmdExecute_Click">
            <Image x:Name="image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="37" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="37" Source="C:\Users\Niclas VMWare\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\CloneMacro\CloneMacro\images\StatusAnnotations_Play_32xLG_color.png"/>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="cmdCancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="395,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="39" Height="40" ToolTip="Cancel" Click="cmdCancel_Click">
            <Image x:Name="imgCancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="37" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="36" Source="C:\Users\Niclas VMWare\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\CloneMacro\CloneMacro\images\CancelApproval_32x32.png"/>
        </Button>
        <CheckBox x:Name="chOpenLastUsed" Content="Open Last Used File" Margin="456,48,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="21" Width="147" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <ListView x:Name="lvStores" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="161" Margin="39,98,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="466">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="Auto">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding sID}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=sName}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Import File" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=sImportFile}"/>
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <Label x:Name="lblProgress" x:FieldModifier="public" Content="Status Text" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40,264,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="465" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FF7C7C7C"/>
        <Button x:Name="ComDialog" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="533,152,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="48" Height="51">
            <Image x:Name="imgComDialog" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="44" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="48" Source="C:\Users\Niclas VMWare\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\CloneMacro\CloneMacro\images\DialogID_6220_32x.png"/>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**CS**

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        // Leave this to show the UI
        InitializeComponent();

        lblProgress.Content = "";


        lvStores.ItemsSource = ReadCSV(@"C:\Users\Niclas VMWare\Downloads\TESTFILE.pcf");

    }

    // Fill ListView
    public class Store
    {
        public string sName { get; set; }
        public string sImportFile { get; set; }
        public string sID { get; set; }
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }

        public Store(string id, string strName, string isChecked, string strImportFile)
        {
            sName = strName.Replace("\"","");
            sImportFile = Path.GetFileName(strImportFile);
            sID = id.Replace("\"","");

            // Convert isChecked to boolean
            // Do convertion outside the constructor to avoid any exception within
            int iBool = Convert.ToInt32(isChecked);

            switch (iBool)
            {
                case 0: IsChecked = false; break;
                case 1: IsChecked = true; break;
                default: throw new InvalidOperationException("Third value in PCF file must be 0 or 1!");
            }
        }
    }
    public IEnumerable<Store> ReadCSV(string fileName)
    {
        // Make sure the file extension is pcf
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(Path.ChangeExtension(fileName, ".pcf").Replace("\"", ""), Encoding.GetEncoding(65001));

        // lines.Select allows to project each line as a Store
        // This will give an IEnumerable<Store> back.
        return lines.Select(line =>
        {
            string[] data = line.Split(',');
            // Return the store data
            // Return id, Name, isChecked (chkbox checked?), filename
            return new Store(data[0], data[1], data[2], fileName);
        });
    }
    // End Fill ListView

    private void cmdDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // if selected
        foreach (var item in lvStores.Items.OfType<Store>())
        {
            if (item.IsChecked == true)
            {
                lvStores.Items.Remove(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The reason `IsChecked` bindings haven't made sense is because you're not following MVVM. You *really* should learn & implement it in your WPF solutions. Once you do, you can listen to `PropertyChanged` on `IsChecked` viewmodel property and remove it from `ObservableCollection`

Comment: Which exception is thrown?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.

Comment: @Yevgeniy Where should I remove the items? In the ReadCSV method? Do you have a sample code? Thank.s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would:

1. Use an ObservableCollection
2. Implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your
   Store class (or something similar... others have suggested, rightly, to  read up on the MVVM paradigm).  These first two are necessary to ensure your
   UI is updating the objects at run-time.
3. Iterate through the loop in
   reverse order, and remove each item one at a time as warranted.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="CloneMacro.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CloneMacro"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Clone Macro" Height="348" Width="620.045">
    <Grid Background="#FFDEDEDE" Margin="-1,0,-8,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="621">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="cmdNew" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="39,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="39" Height="40" ToolTip="New" >
            New
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="cmdOpen" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="39" Height="40" ToolTip="Open" Click="cmdOpen_Click">
            Open
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="cmdSave" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="121,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="39" Height="40" ToolTip="Save">
            Save
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="cmdDelete" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="235,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="39" Height="40" Click="cmdDelete_Click">
            Delete
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="cmdNewStore" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="275,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="39" Height="40">
            New Store
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="cmdExecute" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="355,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="39" Height="40" ToolTip="Execute">
            Execute
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="cmdCancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="395,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="39" Height="40" ToolTip="Cancel">
            Cancel
        </Button>
        <CheckBox x:Name="chOpenLastUsed" Content="Open Last Used File" Margin="456,48,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="21" Width="147" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <ListView x:Name="lvStores" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="161" Margin="39,98,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="466">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="Auto">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding sID}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=sName}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Import File" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=sImportFile}"/>
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <Label x:Name="lblProgress" x:FieldModifier="public" Content="Status Text" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40,264,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="465" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FF7C7C7C"/>
        <Button x:Name="ComDialog" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="533,152,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="48" Height="51">
            Dialog
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace CloneMacro
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ObservableCollection<Store> stores;

        internal const string TESTFILE = @"C:\Temp\TESTFILE.pcf";
        public MainWindow()
        {
            // Leave this to show the UI
            InitializeComponent();

            lblProgress.Content = "";

            OpenFile( TESTFILE );
        }

        internal void OpenFile( string fileName )
        {
            stores = ReadCSV( TESTFILE );
            lvStores.ItemsSource = stores;
        }

        // Fill ListView
        public class Store : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            protected void OnPropertyChanged( string name )
            {
                PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
                if ( handler != null )
                {
                    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
                }
            }

            public string sName { get; set; }
            public string sImportFile { get; set; }
            public string sID { get; set; }

            private bool isChecked;
            public bool IsChecked
            {
                get { return isChecked; }
                set
                {
                    if ( isChecked != value )
                    {
                        isChecked = value;
                        OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
                    }
                }
            }

            public Store( string id, string strName, string isChecked, string strImportFile )
            {
                sName = strName.Replace("\"", "");
                sImportFile = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strImportFile);
                sID = id.Replace("\"", "");

                // Convert isChecked to boolean
                // Do convertion outside the constructor to avoid any exception within
                int iBool = Convert.ToInt32(isChecked);

                switch ( iBool )
                {
                    case 0: IsChecked = false; break;
                    case 1: IsChecked = true; break;
                    default: throw new InvalidOperationException("Third value in PCF file must be 0 or 1!");
                }
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Store> ReadCSV( string fileName )
        {
            // Make sure the file extension is pcf
            string [] lines = File.ReadAllLines(
                System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(fileName, ".pcf").Replace("\"", ""), Encoding.GetEncoding(65001));

            // lines.Select allows to project each line as a Store
            // This will give an IEnumerable<Store> back.
            var enumerable = lines.Select(line =>
            {
                string [] data = line.Split(',');
                // Return the store data
                // Return id, Name, isChecked (chkbox checked?), filename
                return new Store(data [0], data [1], data [2], fileName);
            });

            stores = new ObservableCollection<Store>();
            foreach ( var item in enumerable )
            {
                stores.Add( item );
            }
            return stores;
        }
        // End Fill ListView

        private void cmdDelete_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
        {
            for ( int i = stores.Count - 1; i >= 0; i-- )
            {
                if ( stores[i].IsChecked )
                {
                    stores.RemoveAt( i );
                }
            }
        }

        private void cmdOpen_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
        {
            OpenFile( TESTFILE );
        }

    }
}
```

TESTFILE.pcf:

```
"1662","BØRSTER",0
"1658","BØRSTER",1
"1669","A Møøse once bit my sister.",1
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. You didn't change anything in the XAML? Would you mind putting in some comments in your code? I will start reading up on MVVM :-)

Comment: @Niclas This is the correct way to proceed for your requirements. I'll delete my answer since it is not applicable.

Comment: @Niclas, I didn't really change the XAML from your posted code, except to remove some of the image files that were local to your machine's path.  As far as comments in the code... that will cost extra.  :)  If you have specific questions about anything just ask.